# Delete an inconsistent package fully

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, cuda

I was installing Cuda toolkit [using these instructions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal). But my root partition had very less amount of memory and I had to stop the installation process using `ctrl+c`. Now the package became inconsistent and the memory occupied by it is wasted, so I want to remove it. But when I ran `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-2-local`, it doesn't free the space occupied (I am checking the memory from the output of a conky script). I want to gracefully remove it. Any solution?

Comment: Difficult to gracefully remove if you did not gracefully install (you pressed Ctrl+C).

Comment: Try making some space on your root partition by removing downloaded debs (sudo apt clean), and removing unneeded packages (sudo apt autoremove), which automatically also should remove old kernels (taking each about 400 MB).

Comment: A package takes up *storage* space (disk). A running process takes up *memory*. Files on disk don't directly use memory.

Comment: `man dpkg` clearly shows that `--force-remove-reinstreq` removes none of the package's files at all. You must do that yourself. That flag only marks the package as not-installed-anymore. The cleanup required after using it is one reason why it's generally considered a last-resort for removing a corrupted package.

Comment: @vanadium @user535733 is there any way to manually remove inconsistent packages? `sudo apt autoremove` does not free up space by deleting inconsistent packages it seems.

Comment: Synaptic package manager is excellent to do some manual house cleaning. Click on status, you see different categories, including Installed (local and obsolete). Go through these and carefully remove.

Comment: It is a ppa you have added. Using ppa-purge may also help not only in removing the PPA but also to clean packages coming from that PPA